# GCloud Function not firing after Firestore Create

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've deployed a function to gcloud using the following command line script:

```
gcloud functions deploy my_new_function --runtime python37 \
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create \
--trigger-resource projects/my_project_name/databases/default/documents/experiences/{eventId}
```

This worked successfully, and my function was deployed. Here is what I expected to happen as a result:

Any time a new document was created within the `experiences` firestore collection, the function `my_new_function` would be invoked.

What is actually happening:

`my_new_function` is never being invoked as a result of a new document being created within `experiences`

[image: Trigger]

[image: database]

[image: code]

Comment: How do you know it's not triggering?  What exactly is in your code that should be running but is not?  Are you logging anything to verify this?

Comment: @DougStevenson Inside of my GCloud account I am viewing the function and there are no invocations. When viewing the logs, I only see entires for "Update function", but nothing saying the function was invoked. There is also a `print` statement within the function and it is never output in the logs.

Comment: What exactly are you deploying?  Are you trying to deploy code from your desktop computer?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have a folder `~/Documents/gcloud-functions` within that folder is a single file `main.py` and within that file is a single function `my_new_function(data, context)`. It appears to have been deployed correctly as the "Source" within gcloud functions is showing what is on my machine.

Comment: @DougStevenson Any ideas with the new screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

The --source parameter is for [deploying from source control](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo), which you are not trying to do .  You will want to [deploy from your local machine](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem) instead.  You run gcloud from the directory you want to deploy.

Comment: I made this change and redeployed, but i'm not still seeing any invocations when a new document is created. Perhaps my `--trigger-resource` is wrong? I originally setup this project in Firebase. The only firestorm collection I have is named `experiences` and my project id is `points-experiences`. The `--trigger-resource` I am using is `projects/points-experiences/databases/default/documents/experiences/{eventId}` Note: `eventId` is not a property on a document in the collection, is that okay?

Comment: If you're following the documentation, it should be OK.  There shouldn't be anything fundamentally broken with it.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore

Comment: Since you're not showing code or database screenshots or anything else that one might use to diagnose a problem, I don't think there's much we can do.